# New to elementary, can't find system monitor

Tags: release-freya

I just installed elementary Freya 0.3.2 and I can't find my system monitor. I spent several hours updating the OS after installation, but I want to see if my swap partition is configured to this installation so I would like to open a system monitor in order to see what resources I have available. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

The system monitor is not installed by default in elementary OS. You can install it by opening the terminal and run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-monitor
```

For a better look about the disk partitioning i recommend GParted:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Comment: Thank you. I performed that command and it installed without any problems. I had already installed gparted, but thanks for that tip. Elementary is installed in a multi boot set up with Ubuntu and assorted other Linux distros, but I am still new to Linux and I appreciate any tips or advice.

Comment: Do you do this for trying out new distros by chance? Have you considered using virtual machines for this?

Comment: Yes, I Iike to try different Linux distros installed on my hard drive. I have tried a virtual machine, but I didn't like the way it felt. My system is built with an Intel i5 4690 with 16 gb of DDR3 RAM, but I still like to try out new distros in the real world. Thank you for the suggestion.